# how to let node run the JS file which require scss file

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I am using webpack and node to build my App. The JS code is require scss file.
It looks something like this:

```
require('babel-register');
require("./test.scss");
import React from 'react';

class MyClass extends React.Component
....
```

I have webpack config to bundle all scss into one file

```
{test: /(\.css|\.scss)$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css?sourceMap!sass?sourceMap') },
```

And **webpack configuration is working fine to compile scss to css**. 
However, when I run `node test.js` , it throws some babel-register error which complains about not understanding scss syntax.

I am not sure how we can do it make node or babel understand that scss file should be better handled or even ignored since webpack has already bundle it.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The best workaround for this we've found is to require the SCSS files inside your `componentDidMount`:

```
import React from 'react';

class MyClass extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    require("./test.scss");
  }

  render() {
    return //...
  }
}
```

This way, the node runtime never *sees* the non-JS module, and it still works with webpack since it just looks for the require statement somewhere in your code.

Comment: yep, like the idea to use componentDidMount for client side stuff. I wonder is there any other way we can use, so we can put all the `import` together

Comment: Personally I like "componentizing" my SCSS so each one goes naturally with a component, then let webpack assemble everything. This has the added benefit of automatically excluding SCSS you're not using. Your root component could take care of any global requires